# LassoLars in Scikit Learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

In Scikit-Learn (for some reason I am still on 0.18.x), the `sklearn.linear_model.LassoLars` class after fitting, has the coefficient LARS path as `coef_path_` attribute and the coefficient as `coef_` attribute. I am wondering why the `coef_` values are not the same as the values at the last step of `coef_path_`. Did I misunderstand anything about LARS? By looking at the source code of `_fit()` method of `Lars` class in scikit-learn, `coef_` should be `coef_path_[:,-1]` but some how I have different numbers for these two attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: it is all about the normalization. The difference is if `normalize` is set as `True`, then `coef_path_` are the coefficients based on **normalized** features and `coef_` will be the last slice of `coef_path_` after removing the normalization factor.